# Unmounting tab component in react bootstrap tabs

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

Is there any way to unmount a tab component and mount only the active class to make api request on mounting

Comment: [Bootstrap Tab Component Props](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/tabs/#tabs-props) I think mountOnEnter and unmountOnExit prop is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mountOnEnter="true"` and `unmountOnExit="true"` so it will remove and add to the DOM the component when selecting the tab:

```
<Tabs
  className="mb-3"
  defaultActiveKey="A"
  mountOnEnter={true} <-- this
  unmountOnExit={true} <--- and this
>
  <Tab eventKey="A" title="A">
    <A/>
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="B" title="B">
    <B/>
  </Tab>
  <Tab eventKey="C" title="C">
    <C/>
  </Tab>
</Tabs>
```